# Convert python list into dictionary by mapping list elements to themselves

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

If I have a list that looks like this:

```py
['1 184',
 '1 29',
 '1 31',
 '1 12',
 '1 51',
 '1 102',
 '1 13',
 '1 14',
 '1 15',
 '1 57',
 '1 378',
 '1 859',
 '1 185',
 '1 30',
 '1 37',
 '1 52',
 '1 142',
 '1 195',
 '1 875',
 '1 56',
 '1 66',
 '1 95',
 '1 462',
 '1 497',
 '1 858',
 '1 876',
 '1 879',
 '1 880',
 '2 12',
 '2 15',
 '2 184',
 '2 858',
 '2 51']
```

And I wanted to map the first element of each string to each of the next elements tied to that first number, and get it in the format of `{1 : [184, 29, 31...], 2 : [12, 15, 18, ...]}`.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `lst` is your list from your question then:

```py
out = {}
for a, b in map(str.split, lst):
    out.setdefault(int(a), []).append(int(b))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
    1: [
        184,
        29,
        31,
        12,
        51,
        102,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        57,
        378,
        859,
        185,
        30,
        37,
        52,
        142,
        195,
        875,
        56,
        66,
        95,
        462,
        497,
        858,
        876,
        879,
        880,
    ],
    2: [12, 15, 184, 858, 51],
}
```

---

EDIT: To explicitly check for correct values:

```py
out = {}
for value in lst:
    value = value.split()
    if len(value) == 2:
        a, b = value
        out.setdefault(int(a), []).append(int(b))
```

Comment: Thank you! I am getting a ValueError unfortunately: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)` and the traceback is pointing to `for a, b in map(str.split, lst):`

Comment: @Julien Probably you have some inconsistent values in your list. See my edit.

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Could you quickly explain how it works? I understand what's happening in the first for loop, but not the second. I am not familiar with the `setdefault` function.

Comment: @Julien `out.setdefault(int(a), []).append(int(b))` will first check if `int(a)` is a key in the dictionary `out` - if not, create a list and assign it under this key. Then uses this list to append `int(b)` there. Doc: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question. Does this solve it?

```py
Dictionary = dict() # You must use `dict()` for an empty dictionary because if you write "{}", Python will think it's a set

# Loop through each value in `x`
for Value in x:
    # Get the Key and Value for the Dictionary
    Key,Value = Value.split(" ")

    # If the dictionary's value at key: `Key` has not been set, it will raise a KeyError once called. If this is the case, you must create a blank list for the Value in `Key`
    try:
        Dictionary[Key]
    except KeyError:
        Dictionary[Key] = []

    # Add the Value to the Dictionary at `Key`
    Dictionary[Key].append(Value)
```

Note: `x` is the `list()` in the question

Comment: Your try/except code to determine if `Key` is in `Dictionary` is more typically done with `if Key in Dictionary:`. Also, variable names are typically [lowercase in Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names), and optionally include underscores. It's class names that are capitalized, by PEP8 convention.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on the creation of a pandas dataframe:

```
(pd.DataFrame
 .from_records([list(map(int, x.split())) for x in l], columns=list('ab'))
 .groupby('a')['b'].apply(list).to_dict())
```

Output:

```
{1: [184, 29, 31, 12, 51, 102, 13, 14, 15, 57, 378, 859, 185, 30, 37, 
52, 142, 195, 875, 56, 66, 95, 462, 497, 858, 876, 879, 880], 
2: [12, 15, 184, 858, 51]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a `defauldict` with `list` values

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    k, v = item.split()
    res[int(k)].append(int(v))
```